# Firebase authentication with server, 'is my authentication method safe and effective?'

Tags: laravel, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to make sure whether the way I designed my application's authentication is safe and whether there is better way than this, please give some advice.

This is how the authentication works...

1. Authenticates the user with Firebase from the client application.
2. Receives the token from Firebase and sends it to application's API server.
3. In the API server, using Firebase Admin SDK, authenticates again whether the received token is valid.
4. If it is valid, creates the JWT token from the server and gives it back the client application.
5. Finally, android acquires JWT token and authenticates every API calls with the token.

The reason I'm re-authenticating the token is because I failed to implement Firebase tokens to authenticate API server. It was a big challenge to find sources to find a way to implement them with Laravel.

I'm also curious how people usually use Firebase with separate API servers.

Please note me if the explanation or question is not clear, thanks in advance..

Comment: Need to watch out for [Token sidejacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/JSON_Web_Token_(JWT)_Cheat_Sheet_for_Java#Token_sidejacking)  During authentication, create a fingerprint from the client/agent server side and store it in the server session (or see the example I linked).  If the fingerprint changes at all when making requests, deauthenticate the user (server side) and destroy the JWT.

Comment: Note the code I linked to is just hashing the fingerprint instead of storing it in a server-side session.

Comment: Great answer thanks, never thought of that. So I should hide fingerprint in my server and secretly check whether the client is sending requests with the fingerprints. Got it.

Comment: The code I linked rebuilds the fingerprint on every request and checks the hash stored in the JWT payload (no server-side storage needed).  It's in Java, and you might be able to find a fingerprint plugin for laravel.